# Openshift with cakephp 3

Tags: php, apache, cakephp, openshift

I'm trying to deploy a basic `cakephp3` web application (clean install) using `Openshift Public PaaS` (php+mysql+web load balancer).
Unfortunately, openshift always display the following message :

> 503 Service Unavailable
>   No server is available to handle this request.

I put this cake application in a folder named `application` on `app-repo/runtime/repo` openshift folder.
This application works on my local computer (wampserver).

On openshift :

- If I just put an index.php file with phpinfo(), it works fine.
- .htaccess seams to work too (rewrite engine)

In fact, I think that I get the message when cakephp launch the dispatch (`webroot/index.php`)

```
$dispatcher->dispatch(
Request::createFromGlobals(),
new Response());
```

Openshift log:
(app-root/logs/php.log)

> [Wed Sep 17 15:25:53 2014] [error] [client 127.7.200.0] Attempt to serve directory: /var/lib/openshift/***/app-root/runtime/repo/
>   - - - [17/Sep/2014:15:25:53 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 404 296 "-" "-"

Help! I really don't know what can I do to solve this... Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The load balancer is looking for something to respond on the root context (/) of your application, and since you put your application in a folder named "application" it can't see it, so it thinks the gear is not up, because / is returning a 404 or 503 or something.  So you can either ssh into your main gear and modify the haproxy/haproxy.cfg file to monitor your application context of "/application" or you can provide a file for it to monitor on the root context of index.php

Comment: I changed the line `option httpchk GET /` to `option httpchk GET /application/webroot` followed by a `git push` to restard the cartridge and I have the same error. You're right about the gear, `haproxy.log` : `Server express/local-gear is DOWN, reason: Layer7 wrong status, code: 404, info: "Not Found"`

Comment: Where can I change the DocumentRoot ? It maybe the cause ! Even if I change it in openshift.conf, it remains the same ("/")

Comment: Is /application/webroot what you see in your browser when you visit it locally? or just /application? usually i think webroot is hidden

Comment: I reset my application, now it's running correctly, but I have to use "/application" to get access to the application. That's why I would like to change the DocumentRoot to "~/application/webroot" (http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html) but each time I change openshift.conf or haproxy.cfg and restart with ctl_all restart, all files are reset to the default value.

Comment: Why don't you just rename "application" to "php", or get rid of the application folder alltogether and just have your files in the root directory? both options are supported

Comment: Yes that's what i've done. I thought that we were able to change the documentRoot on openshift ;)